# Returning information from MySQL using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently trying to get into `php` and `MySQL` and i'm using this little project as a learning curve, but I've hit a bump that I can't get through. I have the following code that is accessing my MySQL database and I am currently trying to echo the data out using the following search function:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require("config.php");
ob_end_clean();

$req=$_REQUEST['workingDate'];
$req2=$_REQUEST['location'];

mysql_connect("XXXXXXXXXXX",$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

if ($req!="all" && $req2!="all")  $query="SELECT * FROM TrackerTable WHERE workingDate='$req' AND location1='$req2'";
else if($req=="all" && $req2!="all" ) $query="SELECT * FROM TrackerTable WHERE location1='$req2'";
else if($req!="all" && $req2=="all" ) $query="SELECT * FROM TrackerTable WHERE make='$req'";
else if($req=="all" || $req2=="all" ) $query="SELECT * FROM TrackerTable";

$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_query($result);
mysql_close();

$i=0;

for ($i; $i < $num; $i++){
        $f12=mysql_result($result,$i,"workingDate");
        $f13=mysql_result($result,$i,"location1");
echo $f12." ".$f13."<br />";
}
?>
```

The problem I have is that whenever I try to search the database using the following html form:

```
<form method="post" action="searchFunction.php"  name="input" id="searchform">
    <label class="section">Search Options</label><br />
    <input name="workingDate" type="text" id="workingDate" placeholder="Search by Date">
    <input name="location1" type="text" id="location1" placeholder="Search by Location">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="add" value="Find!">
</form>
```

I get this error thrown at me:

```
 Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /XXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXX/XXXX/XXXXX.com/XXXXXX/searchFunction.php on line 20
```

I have no idea what could be causing the problem as it all seems fairly in place to me. Is there an obvious mistake i'm making or is it all just completely messed up? I've been looking at it that long that I can't tell what makes sense anymore!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: Lovely [Mysql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)...

Comment: Excuse me? Not following what you mean?

Comment: @VeeeneX The guy's new at this clearly, leaving aside the injection, he's using deprecated functions. Anyway, you're passing in $result as the query to be executed. It's not a valid query, in fact the $result would be the return value from the previous query.

Comment: See [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) and  [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: @mario Unfortunately Bobby tables wouldn't work  :( You can't run 2 queries in one statement anymore. But as always xkcd is always relevant.

Comment: Try inserting this `1' OR '1'='1'` into #workingDate

Comment: @mario thanks, i'll take a look soon, but i'm more interested in getting it working first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sure that variable $query is defined? 
This because in the statement if/elseif is where you define the variable $query.

```
   // first define default value for your $query variable
   $query="SELECT * FROM TrackerTable";

   // then use your if/else statement
if ($req!="all" && $req2!="all") .....................
```

You have an error

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_query($result); // error here

mysql_close();
```

$result is not a string, is resource.
mysql_query($result);

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php for details

Comment: Didn't change anything I'm afraid :\

Comment: You call 2 times mysql_query, one with a string (the query) and second with $result that is a resource.

Comment: I've removed the error but now it's just passing a blank screen?

Comment: Use this for show something in the screen: while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['workingDate'];
echo $row['location1'];
echo $row['table_field_name'];
}

Comment: and put mysql_close(); the last line in the script.

Comment: Still show nothing at all, doesn't show anything from the database.

Comment: 1). You need to be sure that you have somthing in database (run all your query to verify you have rows in database).   2). use var_dump for print row content: var_dump($row)

Comment: check sql clause WHERE, ej: workingDate='$req' AND location1='$req2', you have spaces, print your query (echo $query) to se if the query is OK .  I think that your sql query is not ok.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run your query twice:

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
                    ^^^^^^--- your SQL
mysql_query($result);
            ^^^^^^^---- result handle (aka resource) from previous call
```

The second query call is utterly irrelevant/useless. You're passing in the wrong argument to the call, and you're not capturing the return value from the query anyways. Even if it was running properly, you're throwing away the query results.

You then close your DB connection, so when you try to call `mysql_result()` later on, there's no more DB connection to fetch your results from.

And on top of all this, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

In short, this code is a total disaster.

Comment: Ok, is there any resource you can put me toward in terms of doing this properly? I'm now at a lose as to how to proceed with it.